# Gtk TreeView : Connect to double-clicked item / row

Tags: python, gtk3, gtktreeview

I have this `Gtk.TreeView()`

```
treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=liststore)
```

And I get the selected item like this:

```py
selected_playlist_item = treeview.get_selection()
selected_playlist_item.connect("changed", self.on_selected_playlist_item)
```

And here is the `on_selected_playlist_item` callback

```
def on_selected_playlist_item(self, selection):
    model, treeiter = selection.get_selected()
    if treeiter is not None:
        print("You selected", model[treeiter][1])
```

How can I connect only to the double-click / return selection, and not just a single click / movement in the listview?

I have been [looking](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/api/signals.html?highlight=change-state%20signals) in [a lot](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/treeview.html#the-selection) of [places](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-connecting-signal-handlers.html.en) for a list of possible signals, but to no avail ; If somebody knows where to find such documentation, that would be a nice bonus, I have other `connect()` issues like that.

Answer (score 1):

I got [the answer](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeView.html#Gtk.TreeView.signals.row_activated):

Connect the TreeView itself (not the row / selection like I was doing) to the `row-activated` signal:

```
self.treeview.connect("row-activated", self.cb)
```

(Click click / Return)

```
def cb(self, tree_view, path, column):
    print("Selected!!")
```

Comment: Could explain the difference between the two methods? I would have thought they would be equivalent. Thanks.